# Zeep Client Service Request missing element

Tags: python-3.x, soap-client, zeep

***new to Python/Zeep, please be gentle***

when posting the following to my endpoint, all is working as expected:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <Body>
        <PassThroughReq xmlns="http://amsservices.com/">
            <XMLinput>
                <INPUT>
                    <Account value="account" />
                    <Username value="username" />
                    <Password value="password" />
                    <Serverpool value="serverpool" />
                    <ProgramName name="WEBSERVICE.GET.POLICY.DATA.IDS" />
                    <Command cmd="279898" />
                </INPUT>
            </XMLinput>
        </PassThroughReq>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I'm attempting to replicate the request with the following code:

```
import os
from zeep import Client

account = os.environ.get('sgws_account')
username = os.environ.get('sgws_username')
password = os.environ.get('sgws_password')
serverpool = os.environ.get('sgws_serverpool')
wsdl = os.environ.get('sgws_wsdl')

client = Client(wsdl)

xmlInput = {
    'INPUT':{
        'Account':account,
        'Username':username,
        'Password':password,
        'Serverpool':serverpool,
        'ProgramName':'WEBSERVICE.GET.POLICY.DATA.IDS',
        'Command':'279898'
    }
}

ptr = client.get_element('ns0:PassThroughReq')(xmlInput)

client.service.PassThroughReq(XMLinput=ptr)
```

the result is "Missing element for Any"

I've also tried the request as follows, with the same result:

```
client.service.PassThroughReq(ptr)
```

relative Global elements in the wdsl are:

```
ns0:PassThroughReq(XMLinput: {_value_1: ANY})
```

I will paste the full Traceback in a comment below.

I'm hoping this is a simple miss, due to ignorance, on my part but any light you may be able to shed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Traceback is too long for comments, but I'm happy to post anything you may deem relevant

Comment: if possible show us the definition of `PassThroughReq` from `python -mzeep wsdl.url`